# BigQuery SQL to track dwell time in point of interest from location data with multiple stops

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working on a dataset with anonymized location data and I receive a series of time-stamp intervals at various points of interest. I'm trying to calculate the dwell time for an individual within a point of interest. I've tried a simple method of max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) to calculate a time difference. This works well for many of the devices in the dataset, but not if the user returns to a place multiple times. I'm missing some step to group the data whenever there is a change in location and calculate the interval for that group of timestamps.

Here is a subset of the data:

```
ID, Location, UnixTimestamp
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 07:42:39
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:50:22
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:50:23
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:50:28
IDABCDE,"Place_1",2018-03-16 12:58:27
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:58:27
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 13:02:45
IDABCDE,"Place_1",2018-03-16 13:02:45
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:05:47
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:05:54
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:05:57
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:10:19
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:11:13
IDABCDE,"Place_1",2018-03-16 14:11:13
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:13:03
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:01
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:01
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:08
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:14
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:17:08
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:17:31
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:18:07
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:18:07
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:18:07
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:02:04
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:02:04
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:02:19
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:03:17
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:03:17
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 15:05:34
```

The query should return a duration for the grouping of values for the first instance of Place 2, 0 for Place 1 (only one observation), calculate a second dwell time for place_2, 0 for a second visit to place_1, then a dwell time for Place_3.

I've tried variations on the following:

```
SELECT ID, location, 
min(Unix_Timestamp) as first_observation, max(Unix_Timestamp) as last_observation,
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(max(Unix_Timestamp),min(Unix_Timestamp), minute) as time_in_location
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY ID, location
```

This returns the time difference between the first and last values of each place (which is what the query is asking for, but isn't quite what I need).

I believe I need a window function, but trying different Partition_By values still isn't returning the correct result.

Any insight you have is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the segmentation code you're looking for:

```sql
SELECT *, SUM(x) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY unix_timestamp, location) segmentId
FROM (
  SELECT *, IF(LAG(location) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY unix_timestamp, location)=location,0,1) x
  FROM data
)
```

With this your existing code will run as expected with a minimal modification: `GROUP BY ..., segment_id`.

```sql
WITH data AS (
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'([^\,]*),') id
, REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r',([^\,]*),') location
, TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r',([^\,]*)$')) unix_timestamp
FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("""IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 07:42:39
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:50:22
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:50:23
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:50:28
IDABCDE,"Place_1",2018-03-16 12:58:27
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 12:58:27
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 13:02:45
IDABCDE,"Place_1",2018-03-16 13:02:45
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:05:47
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:05:54
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:05:57
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:10:19
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 14:11:13
IDABCDE,"Place_1",2018-03-16 14:11:13
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:13:03
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:01
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:01
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:08
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:16:14
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:17:08
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:17:31
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:18:07
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:18:07
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 14:18:07
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:02:04
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:02:04
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:02:19
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:03:17
IDABCDE,"Place_3",2018-03-16 15:03:17
IDABCDE,"Place_2",2018-03-16 15:05:34""", '\n')) x
)

, dataprep AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(x) OVER(ORDER BY unix_timestamp, location) segmentId
  FROM (
    SELECT *, IF(LAG(location) OVER(ORDER BY unix_timestamp, location)=location,0,1) x
    FROM data
  )
)

SELECT
  ID, location, 
  min(Unix_Timestamp) as first_observation, max(Unix_Timestamp) as last_observation,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(max(Unix_Timestamp),min(Unix_Timestamp), second) as time_in_location
  , COUNT(*) steps
FROM dataprep
GROUP BY ID, location, segmentId
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm running the query and it keeps failing with an error that I've exceeded memory usage: 
"Query failed: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 114% of limit.
Top memory consumer(s):
sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 97%
other/unattributed: 3%"

Doo you have any recommendations for how to run this on a large dataset without exceeding available resources?

Comment: It must be this: `OVER(ORDER)` statements. Try `OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY unix_timestamp, location)`, and `OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY unix_timestamp, location)`